# Group data by age, gender and report requested in MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by, having

I'm having trouble formulating my MySQL statement / query string. I have a table (see sample below)

[image: MySQL sample Table]

It's a sample table containing gender, age and report_requested fields. What I would like to have as an output is something like this:

```
20 years old, male | Total number of users | Total who requested min 1 report | total who requested 2 reports | total 3 or more reports

20 years old female | Total number of users | Total who requested min 1 report | total who requested 2 reports | total 3 or more reports

20 years old combined | Total number of users | Total who requested min 1 report | total who requested 2 reports | total 3 or more reports

21 years old, male | Total number of users | Total who requested min 1 report | total who requested 2 reports | total 3 or more reports

21 years old female | Total number of users | Total who requested min 1 report | total who requested 2 reports | total 3 or more reports

21 years old combined | Total number of users | Total who requested min 1 report | total who requested 2 reports | total 3 or more reports
```

... etc.

But I'm having a hard time with it. What I just know is to determine the number of users who requested (1,2,3,...etc) credit reports given the gender and age.

Here's what I used:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as cnt, report_requested 
FROM sampletable WHERE age = '39' 
AND gender = 'M' GROUP BY report_requested
```

Here's the result:

[image]

It just return the data for 20 yrs old male, number of users requested 1 credit report, 2 credit reports up to 8 (but this is also wrong since it should combine the number of users who requested 3 credit reports or more)

Can anybody here help me or give me an idea on how I could accomplish this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `GROUP BY` clause is actually both `age` and `gender` since you are trying to aggregate for these two. The way to think about it is that you want exactly one row per `age` and `gender`, i.e. 1 row for male/20 yrs, 1 row for female/20 yrs, 1 row for male/21 yrs, etc. So you would do:

```
GROUP BY age, gender
```

And instead of `report_requested` column, I think you need to `SUM(report_requested)` with a condition on the number of reports requested. This is handled in SQL via the `CASE` clause. So your query would look like this:

```
SELECT AGE, GENDER, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN report_requested = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total who requested 1 report',
    SUM(CASE WHEN report_requested = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total who requested 2 reports',
    SUM(CASE WHEN report_requested >= 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Total who requested 3 or more reports'
FROM sampletable 
GROUP BY AGE, GENDER
```

Let me know how it goes. I removed the `WHERE` clause because I assumed that was for testing only.

EDIT: Updated after the comments below, that it's not the total requested rather total who requested 1 report, total who requested 2 reports, etc.

Comment: Is it really AGE(report_requested) or SUM(report_requested) ?

Comment: Indeed, it is SUM(report_requested), thanks for pointing it out. I fixed it.

Comment: It worked somehow but it only displayed the total number of credit reports requested for each age/gender (Total Requested). I still need to get teh breakdown of the total requested reports (no. of users who requested 1 credit report, 2 credit reports, etc.)

Comment: I think I might need to use HAVING... ? Not so sure.

Comment: I misunderstood that part from your question, but have updated my response, try it. You will need HAVING clause typically if you needed to filter by an aggregate function (such as HAVING count(*) > 5 so that only those rows will be displayed where the total count of selected rows is more than 5). I don't think that applies to your case.